# Check multiple checkbox of nested ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have $scope.getmaindata list with 5 objects, in each object i have a list contain multiple values which user achieved. And $scope.myproviders contain levels with id and level name. I want to check the multiple values of each user corresponded to that service when id matches. and if user have level 3 in his list i have to show the input box next to it. I tried some answers in stackoverflow but none of them solved my issue.The problem i am getting with code is when the levelsqualified list of the each user is not in the order, so i thought i have to write a for loop and wrote but not succeeded.
 Here is the working plunkr with more code  [Plunkr v1](http://plnkr.co/edit/v6xYM9?p=preview)
**Update**
The values are binding for the first time with $scope variables but when i uncheck some of them *levelsqualified* list of each user is not updated
[Plunkr v2](http://plnkr.co/edit/mx1Pfm?p=preview)

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" ng-repeat="mydata in getmaindata">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <h4>{{mydata.firstname}}</h4>
        <li ng-repeat="providers in myproviders">
          <span>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="providercheck{{$index}}" name="amlcprovidercheck{{$index}}" ng-model="mydata.checkedList" 
                ng-checked="mydata.levelsqualified[$index]==providers.level">
                  {{providers.level}}
              </label>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="required-field-block">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="show if user have third level is checked" ng-model="maindata.other_provider" />
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change your ng-checked (if I am understanding you correctly).

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="providercheck{{$index}}" name="amlcprovidercheck{{$index}}" ng-model="mydata.checkedList" 
        ng-checked="mydata.levelsqualified[$index]">
            {{providers.level}}
</label>
```

and you need to add an `ng-if` for your input box like so:

```
<li ng-if="mydata.levelsqualified[$index]==3">
    <div class="required-field-block">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="show if third level is checked" ng-model="maindata.other_provider" />
    </div>
</li>
```

I hope this is what you needed.

> EDIT
>   I changed the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kUY8Xq?p=preview) to incorporate both answers and a little hacking.  I added an ng-change event and changed your `ng-model`.  See Below:

```
<li ng-repeat="providers in myproviders">
    <span>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="amlcprovidercheck{{$index}}" ng-model="mydata.selected" ng-change="addCheckChoice(mydata, providers)" ng-checked="mydata.levelsqualified.indexOf(providers.id) > -1">
                {{providers.level}}
        </label>
    </span>
</li>
<li ng-if="mydata.levelsqualified.indexOf(3) > -1">
    <div class="required-field-block">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="show if third level is checked" ng-model="maindata.other_provider" />
    </div>
</li>
```

I also added the following function:

```
$scope.addCheckChoice = function (c, p) {
    var main = $scope.getmaindata.indexOf(c);
    var idx = c.levelsqualified.indexOf(p.id);
    if (c.selected === true) {
        c.levelsqualified.push(p.id);
        alert("You selected " + p.id + " for " + c.firstname);
    }
    else {
        c.levelsqualified.splice(idx, 1);

        alert("You removed " + p.id + " for " + c.firstname)

    }
    for (var i = 0; i < c.levelsqualified.length; i++) {
        for(var x = 0; x < $scope.myproviders.length; x++){
            if (c.levelsqualified[i] == $scope.myproviders[x].id) {
                c.selected = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If this isn't what you need, let me know.  You may need to do a little tweaking.

Comment: In the Plunker, if we have `levelsqualified: [2]` for John in `$scope.getmaindata` the checkbox which is selected is 'first' expected is 'second'. It's coz of this `ngchecked="mydata.levelsqualified[$index]"` no matter what the first element is, in levelsqualified, the checkbox that will be selected is 'first'. I guess that's wrong.

Comment: 1) thanks for the answer, but for user 'nerd' it should select 3,2 instead of that, its selected 2,1. Do you know why? 2) As @raksmen mentioned if you change the list values of any user without having 1 in it but its making first has checked. 3) i have to send those checked items of all user along with input if it exist to server with a click of button. what will be the output look like

Comment: When i select one checkbox of a user it auto selects all other check boxes of that user, and when i deselect a checkbox it deselect all check boxes of the that user, all these happening after alert message. Can you look at this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Randi Radcliff's plunker, [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ohw8oO) plunker might do the trick.

On the ng-checked just did:

```
ng-checked="mydata.levelsqualified.indexOf(providers.id) > -1"
```

Comment: thanks, when i uncheck some elements the values are not removed from `levelsqualified` list of each user

Comment: I see many of the components are missing in the plunker. Where is `ng-model="letchecked"` in the script.js? Similarly `providercheck{{$index}}` `ng-model="mydata.other_provider"` etc